# auto nginx proxy for dockerized websites

Tags: nginx, proxy, docker, dns, weave

Hello stackoverflow community!

I am currently having this scenario with dockerized websites.

Host Machine
- Website A
- Website B
- Website C

All of the websites have different domains. Right now I make a manual proxy_pass from the host machine nginx to the website dockers. e.G. Website A listen to port 9001:80, Website B listen to port 9002:80.

What I want to achieve is, that I don't have to assign a special port to every container, but having one docker reverse proxy container which acts as a dns/reverse proxy for all other containers.

What is the best-practise to do this?

I found this
http://weave.works/
and this
http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/03/25/automated-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-docker/

Where the last one still have a lot of issues and I don't know if it's ready for production.

Best Regards,
Taylor

Comment: What are the issues with nginx-proxy? (https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) Basically, it automatically configures a regular nginx proxy, so I don't see real issues for it not being production ready. This one may become interesting as well https://github.com/EmileVauge/traefik

Comment: the problem with nginx-proxy is that it forces me to use ssl on all pages. =/ thank you for the tip with traefik!

Comment: "the problem with nginx-proxy is that it forces me to use ssl on all pages". I think this is best practice as well; having only SSL for certain pages (e.g., Only for the login-form) is a security risk; http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/05/your-login-form-posts-to-https-but-you.html